# external link to laravel app gives a token mismatch error

Tags: laravel-5

I don't know what is going wrong.

On a external website, i have a link to the login screen for my laravel 5.0 app.

When i click on the external link, the login page of my laravel app opens in a new tab.

But when i submit my login form, i get a token mismatch error. When i type in the url in the address bar, i don't get a token mismatch error when i submit my login form.

I've searched google, stackoverflow, laracasts, but everywhere they talk about ajax and i don't use a ajax request to post my login form.

I hope someone can help me out.
Thanks in advance

Sorry for my bad english.

//EDIT

```
//link on external website
<a href="www.my-domain.com/login>Login</a>

//my form
<form action="/login" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}>
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="password">
<button>Login</button>
</form>
```

There can be some typo's in this code. But there are none in my actual code. Just when i come from the external link to my form i get the Token Mismatch Error. NOT when i type the link in my address bar.

Comment: Post some code and specifics of the error message

Comment: What code is needed? I think it's straight forward, on my laravel site i have a login form with a csrf_field. On a external site there is a link to my login screen on my laravel site, not included in the external site. And ONLY then the problem occures, not when i go to my site by address bar.

Comment: You won't get any useful help if you don't post your code and specifics of your error. Your choice though you can keep your question like it is and you will see how many answers you get

Answer (score 0):

You need a `csrf_token` in your form, which is generated by Laravel.  So if you don't have the log-in on your laravel site, you can do one of two things:

1. Remove csrf protection on the login route (not recommended). This will let people log in to your app from any site, and isn't very safe.
2. Load the login form from your laravel site. have your external site call over to Laravel to get the login form, and include a `csrf_token` in the form.  Then you can print the form on the external site and it will have the proper token.

Comment: I have a csrf_field in my form and the form is on my laravel site, the problem occures only when i click the link in a external site to my login screen that is located in my laravel site. Otherwise it won't have the problem.